# Collect json disordered, order it and show it in chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, chart.js

I'm calling a currency exchange api that returns a json disordered with 2 arrays and I need to get the date in a variable and the corresponding value in another variable to be able to show the data posteriormentes in a graph with chart.js.

The JSON I receive is the following:

```
{"rates": {
        "2018-05-04": {"USD": 1.1969},
        "2018-08-27": {"USD": 1.1633},
        "2018-06-08": {"USD": 1.1754},
        "2018-08-22": {"USD": 1.1616},
        "2018-07-19": {"USD": 1.1588}
          }
}
```

I make the call by ajax with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '(WEBSITE)', // Skipped to avoid spamming
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {},
   success: function (data) {         
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

      // I take the JSON to see the dates
      var var2 = data.rates;
      var fecha = Object.keys(var2);
      var fecha = fecha;
      console.log( fecha ); // Output ["2018-05-04", "2018-08-27", "2018-06-08", "2018-08-22", "2018-07-19"]

       // CHART
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
       // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',
          // The data for our dataset
           data: {
             labels: fecha,
             datasets: [{
               label: 'Prueba chart',
               backgroundColor: 'rgb(125, 255, 238)',
               borderColor: 'rgb(59, 255, 229)',
               data: valores
             }]
            },
            // Configuration options go here
             options: {}
          });
       },
      error: function (error) { console.log(error); }
    });
```

However if I try to take the values of each coin using a "for in" loop it shows me the following result:

```
for (fecha in var2) {
 console.log( [var2[fecha].USD] );
 var valores = [var2[fecha].USD];
}
// Output a record for each row, not an array:
[1.1969]
[1.1633]
[1.1754]
[1.1616]
[1.1588]
```

How could I sort the dates with their corresponding values and associate the dates to the label "labels" and the values of the currencies to the label "data" of chart.js?

What I want to get is this:

```
var fechas = ["2018-05-04", "2018-06-08", "2018-07-19","2018-08-22","2018-08-27"]; // Ordered Dates

var valores = ["1.1969", "1.1754", "1.1588","1.1616","1.1633"]; // Value of the currencies corresponding to the ordered date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are always in the format YYYY-MM-DD as shown in your example, you can sort them alphabetically like this:

```js
const rates = {
   "2018-05-04": {"USD": 1.1969},
   "2018-08-27": {"USD": 1.1633},
   "2018-06-08": {"USD": 1.1754},
   "2018-08-22": {"USD": 1.1616},
   "2018-07-19": {"USD": 1.1588}
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(rates));

const sorted = {};
Object.keys(rates).sort().forEach(key => {
  sorted[key] = rates[key];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));

//EDIT:
//In case you only want the values without the dates in an array:

const sortedValues = [];
let i = 0;
Object.keys(rates).sort().forEach(key => {
  sortedValues.push(rates[key].USD);
});

console.log(sortedValues);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, "rates" enters as an array not as a variable, so the loop you gave me would not work properly (but again, thank you for your answer).

On the other hand, I would need to be able to separate in an orderly way the dates to assign it in the chart.js "labels" label and the value corresponding to each date to introduce it in the chart.js "data" label.